# android floodfill opencv UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, image-processing, opencv, flood-fill

Story:
On the android screen I display a picture with a ruler in it. I klick inside the ruler and floodfill it like this:

```
1Imgproc.floodFill(image0, mask, seed, new Scalar(20,40,60));
```

Unfortunately the results are bad, because the contours of the ruler are not closed and the picture is filled nearly completely.
Better results returned from the floodfill.cpp sample on my desktop pc which I tried to execute analogical on the android like this:

```
2Imgproc.floodFill(image0, mask, seed, new Scalar(50,70,90), rect, new Scalar(20,20,20), new Scalar(20,20,20), Imgproc.FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE);
```

Here I get the UnsatisfiedLinkError.
How is this possible? Improc.floodfill(...
offers four different floodfill variations (with different parameters) and only the first one (number 1) works. All others: UnsatisfiedLinkError

Question:
Does this mean that the other variations are offered but just not implemented?

€dit: The error occurs [here](http://pastebin.com/dWifW3me) in line 96. And the logcat output can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/hMLZ9C3e).